# isolating a sub-string in a string before a symbol in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, substring

i am trying to extract a substring(everything before a hyphen, in this case) from a string as shown below:

```
Net Operating Loss - 2007
Capital Loss - 1991
Foreign Tax Credit - 1997
```

and want the year and name(substring before hyphen) separately, using SQL server Management studio 2008. Any advice? or idea how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(100)

SET @test = 'Foreign Tax Credit - 1997'

SELECT @test, left(@test, charindex('-', @test) - 2) AS LeftString,
    right(@test, len(@test) - charindex('-', @test) - 1)  AS RightString
```

Comment: Should that - 2 be - 1?

Comment: no, there are spaces on both sides of the char '-' @MaxJ

Comment: @pbordeaux - Ah, yes - missed that, apologies. Was not the case in what I required this for and overlooked that

Answer (score 7):

```
DECLARE @dd VARCHAR(200) = 'Net Operating Loss - 2007';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@dd, 1, CHARINDEX('-', @dd) -1) F1,
       SUBSTRING(@dd, CHARINDEX('-', @dd) +1, LEN(@dd)) F2
```

Answer (score 1):

This can achieve using two SQL functions- SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX

You can read strings to a variable as shown in the above answers, or can add it to a SELECT statement as below:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Net Operating Loss - 2007' ,0, CHARINDEX('-','Net Operating Loss - 2007'))
```