# T-SQL 'InString' or Remove operation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to do a some kind of inline operation to remove a certain portion of the value being retrieved? For example, I have

```
SELECT VersionNumber, [Description], 
FROM tblVersions
```

and values for `VersionNumber` may be
EDIT: Come to discover that a whole number can be a value such as 1, 25, 100, etc. So in that case `CHARINDEX` and `LEFT` won't work.

```
 1.1
 1.55
10.01
10.99
99.1 (a)
50.17 Interim
```

What I need to do is cut everything after the period (the value type is `VARCHAR`). This is part of a `PIVOT` query (see below) so the actual `Select` statement is part of a fixed string.

```
SELECT 
   @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT '],[' + [Description] 
FROM 
   GIIA.vQualScoringGrade 
ORDER BY 
   '],[' + [Description] 
FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') + ']'

SET @query = N'SELECT VersionNumber, ' + @cols + 
              ' FROM (SELECT VersionNumber, Description, Value, OrderBy FROM GIIA.vQualScoringGrade) p
PIVOT (SUM([Value]) for [Description] IN ( ' + @cols + ' )) AS pvt ORDER BY VersionNumber'

execute(@query)
```

Comment: The CHARINDEX and LEFT functions should suffice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [isolating a sub-string in a string before a symbol in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651074/isolating-a-sub-string-in-a-string-before-a-symbol-in-sql-server-2008). If the period is only in some strings then you can add `CASE` to handle that: `select case when charindex('.', VersionNumber) = 0 then VersionNumber else ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [isolating a sub-string in a string before a symbol in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651074/isolating-a-sub-string-in-a-string-before-a-symbol-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial understanding of what sort of value can be had in the VersionNumber field was off. Basically I can have text, numbers that look like decimals, or whole numbers. The requirement is to keep this filed an "open" text which makes it difficult for the programmer, but what else is new?

So as @Pondlife suggested, I've implemented a `SELECT CASE` statement and for the most part it works - I have ordering issues but I can deal with that later.

I've ended up modifying the view that feeds the sproc like this:

```
 SELECT CASE CHARINDEX('.', VersionNumber) WHEN 0 THEN VersionNumber ELSE REPLACE(LEFT(VersionNumber, CHARINDEX('.', VersionNumber)), '.', '') 
 END AS [Award Fee Period], 'Unsatisfactory' AS Description, COUNT(Description) AS GradeCount, 6 AS OrderBy
 FROM GIIA.vQualScoringGrade
```

So many thanks to all who contributed!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want something like:

```
LEFT(VersionNumber, CHARINDEX('.',VersionNumber + '.')-1)
```

Adding your own period is a little trick to make it work whether or not the original string has a period in it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method for getting just the major version is probably appending a period and using left/charindex:

```
select left(VersionNumber, charindex('.', VersionNumber + '.') - 1) as Major
from tblVersions
```

I've also used parsename for getting all four parts of a version number:

```
select VersionNumber
    , parsename(VersionNumber + replicate('.0', 3 - (len(VersionNumber) - len(replace(VersionNumber, '.', '')))), 4) as Major
    , parsename(VersionNumber + replicate('.0', 3 - (len(VersionNumber) - len(replace(VersionNumber, '.', '')))), 3) as Minor
    , parsename(VersionNumber + replicate('.0', 3 - (len(VersionNumber) - len(replace(VersionNumber, '.', '')))), 2) as Build
    , parsename(VersionNumber + replicate('.0', 3 - (len(VersionNumber) - len(replace(VersionNumber, '.', '')))), 1) as Revision
from tblVersions
```

Anything beyond four elements separated by a period would probably be best done using any number of T-SQL splitters out there (Tally, CTE, UDF, XML).