# Split string of variable length, variable delimiters

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2017

Read the question posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651074/isolating-a-sub-string-in-a-string-before-a-symbol-in-sql-server-2008), but mine is a little more complicated.

I have a string that is variable in length, and the delimiter can sometimes be two dashes, or sometimes it can be just one. Let's say in my table the data that I want to break out is stored in a single column like this:

```
+ -----------------------------------------+
| Category                                 |
+------------------------------------------+
| Zoo - Animals - Lions                    |
| Zoo - Personnel                          |
| Zoo - Operating Costs - Power / Cooling  |
+------------------------------------------+
```

But I want to output the data string from that single column into three separate columns like this:

```
+----------+--------------------+-----------------+
| Location | Category           | Sub-Category    |
+----------+--------------------+-----------------+
| Zoo      | Animals            | Lions           |
| Zoo      | Personnel          |                 |
| Zoo      | Operating Costs    | Power / Cooling |
+----------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

Hoping for some guidance as the samples I've been finding on Google seem to be simpler than this.

Comment: Is Location - Category - Sub-Category always the order?

Comment: To output them where in which language?

Comment: @squillman Yes, it will always be in that order. There will always be a location and category, but the sub-category is optional and therefore can sometimes be NULL. Also, "Zoo" is just an example of the location; the location can be a variable length up to 255 characters. Same with category and sub-category.

Comment: @JQSOFT It's the result of a SQL query where the column name in the table is Category.

Comment: What compatibility level is your database operating in?

Comment: When you say "the delimiter can sometimes be two dashes" do you mean `'Zoo -- Guests'` would be `'Zoo'`, `'Guests'` rather than `'Zoo'`, _null_, `'Guests'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a string splitter. Here is an excellent one that works with your version. [DelimitedSplit8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)

Now we need some sample data.

```
declare @Something table
(
    Category varchar(100)
)

insert @Something values
('Zoo - Animals - Lions')
, ('Zoo - Personnel')
, ('Zoo - Operating Costs - Power / Cooling')
```

Now that we have a function and sample data the code for this is quite nice and tidy.

```
select s.Category
    , Location = max(case when x.ItemNumber = 1 then Item end)
    , Category = max(case when x.ItemNumber = 2 then Item end)
    , SubCategory = max(case when x.ItemNumber = 3 then Item end)
from @Something s
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(s.Category, '-') x
group by s.Category
```

And this will return:

```
Category                                |Location|Category       |SubCategory
Zoo - Animals - Lions                   |Zoo     |Animals        |Lions
Zoo - Operating Costs - Power / Cooling |Zoo     |Operating Costs|Power / Cooling
Zoo - Personnel                         |Zoo     |Personnel      |NULL
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with my database, probably because it's 2012, even though it says 2017. The DBAs control that based on corporate governance.

Comment: Did you read the article linked? You need to have the function DelimitedSplit8K. And yes it works just fine with 2012, works as far back as sql server 2005 when they first introduced ctes and table valued functions.

Comment: Fortunately I was able to create the function and it works a treat! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses solely string functions:

```
select 
    left(
        category, 
        charindex('-', category) - 2
    ) location,
    substring(
        category, 
        charindex('-', category) + 2, 
        len(category) - charindex('-', category, charindex('-', category) + 1)
    ) category,
    case when charindex('-', category, charindex('-', category) + 1) > 0 
        then right(category, charindex('-', reverse(category)) - 2) 
    end sub_category
from t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e691f5aaa2fb4ad629fd421644d717c3)**:

```
location | category         | sub_category   
:------- | :--------------- | :--------------
Zoo      | Animal           | Lions          
Zoo      | Personnel        | null           
Zoo      | Operating Costs  | Power / Cooling
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the route which will most likely go, but I'm getting some inconsistent results. Sometimes the data splits out nicely, somethings it does not and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this with `[sql-server-2017]`. That means, that you can use JSON-support (this was introduced with v2016).

Currently JSON is the best *built-in* approach for position- and type-safe string splitting:

A mockup, to simulate your issue

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Category VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @mockup (Category)
VALUES ('Zoo - Animals - Lions')
      ,('Zoo - Personnel')
      ,('Zoo - Operating Costs - Power / Cooling');
```

--The query

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,A.[Location] 
      ,A.Category 
      ,A.subCategory 
FROM @mockup t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('[["',REPLACE(t.Category,'-','","'),'"]]')) 
WITH ([Location] VARCHAR(MAX) '$[0]'
     ,Category VARCHAR(MAX) '$[1]'
     ,SubCategory VARCHAR(MAX) '$[2]') A;
```

The result (might need some `TRIM()`ing)

```
ID  Location    Category            subCategory
1   Zoo         Animals             Lions
2   Zoo         Personnel           NULL
3   Zoo         Operating Costs     Power / Cooling
```

The idea in short:

We use some simple string operations to transform your string into a JSON array:

```
a b c    => [["a","b","c"]]
```

Now we can use `OPENJSON()` together with a `WITH`-clause to return each fragment by its position with a fixed type.

Comment: Yes, I tagged it 2017 and probably shouldn't have given that the compatibility level is set to 110.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of  hack, but it works:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Category VARCHAR(255))

INSERT @t (Category)
VALUES ('Zoo - Animals - Lions'),('Zoo - Personnel'),('Zoo - Operating Costs - Power / Cooling')

;WITH split_vals AS (
    SELECT Category AS Cat,TRIM(Value) AS Value,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Category) AS RowNum
    FROM @t
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Category,'-')
), cols AS (
    SELECT
        Cat,
        CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN Value END AS Location,
        CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN Value END AS Category,
        CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN Value END AS [Sub-Category]
    FROM split_vals
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(Location, '') AS Location,
       STRING_AGG(Category, '') AS Category,
       STRING_AGG([Sub-Category], '') AS [Sub-Category]
FROM cols
GROUP BY Cat;
```

Comment: Getting this: 
'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name.
'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: And you're using SQL 2017? What compatability level is your database set to?

Comment: 110...I don't have any control over that, I'm in corporate environment.

Comment: Oy...  110 is SQL 2012 compatability.  You should have a chat with your DBA.

Comment: @squillman `STRING_SPLIT()` is not guaranteed to return the fragments in the same order they were passed into. This might work in all internal tests, pass any validation and still break in production (with absolutely silly errors, which drive you crazy). I just placed an answer with a position- and type-safe splitter using JSON (but this won't work with compatibility 110 either :-()

Comment: @Shnugo Ahhh, yeah I just confirmed that.  I've never seen it do otherwise but I also didn't read the doc enough (or bother to check).  But you're absolutely right.  I'm really glad you pointed that out to me!

Comment: @squillman To be honest: I think, that the developes just did not think about this at all... `STRING_SPLIT()` is of little or no use without a second column for the item's position. And nobody bothered to think about this. As far as I know, the hint about the sort order (in the docs) was added later, when they found, that in bigger context (due to parallelism?) this may break. However, we can use JSON, which is really fast luckily.

Comment: @Shnugo Yeah, I'd agree with that.  Love the JSON solution.  I use JSON all over the place in our apps, even replaced other things (like table parameters) with it because of how fast it is.  Hadn't thought about using it just for positioning.  Good stuff.